# UIpicker view data source

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm a IOS noob  and I'm trying to understand how to set the datasource of of the uipicker view
i have followed [This](http://cocoamatic.blogspot.com/2010/08/create-uipickerview-programmatically.html) tutorial, everything seems to work correctly however i get a warning in xcode that says

```
'id<UIPickerViewDataSource>' from incompatible type 'StateViewController *const __strong'
```

it occurs on this line.

```
myPickerView.delegate = self;
```

I keep trying different things but they all lead me in the same direction. It fails.
How should i be doing this? how to i properly set the datasource of a UIpicker view.

Thanks in advance for your guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to tell the compiler that you're going to conform to the delegate protocol. You do that by adding `<UIPickerViewDataSource>` to your .h file,

```
@interface StateViewController : UIViewController <UIPickerViewDataSource>
```

Comment: god i feel like such an idiot thanks for the answer. I tried for ours to change the data source to and array to then a dictionary the list goes on and on.

Answer (score 1):

You need to say

```
myPickerView.dataSource = self
```

and also

```
<UIPickerViewDataSource>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1:** Add `UIPickerViewDataSource` delegate in your header file

```
@interface StateViewController : UIViewController <UIPickerViewDataSource>
```

**Step 2:** Now add the following line in your class file

```
myPickerView.dataSource = self
```